# LINQ to SQL translation to SQL of custom method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to translate an expression to SQL to use with [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL)?

For example I have a method that compares two values.

Example:

```
MyComparer.Compare(value1, value2, ">") return value1 > value2
MyComparer.Compare(value1, value2, "=") return value1 == value2
MyComparer.Compare(value1, value2, "<=") return value1 <= value2
```

And I would like a query like:

```
var list = from i in dataContext.items
           where MyComparer.Compare(i.value, someValue, "some operator")
           select ...
```

This won't work because, obviously, `MyComparer` doesn't translate to SQL.

Maybe this is a twisted question, but how can I translate this method to SQL or is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most pragmatic option may be compositon:

```
// build the core query
var list = from i in dataContext.items
           // most of your query
           select ...

// compose the value-filter if required
switch(someOperator) {
    case "=": list = list.Where(row => row.value1 == row.value2); break;
    case ">": list = list.Where(row => row.value1 > row.value2); break;
    case "<": list = list.Where(row => row.value1 < row.value2); break;
}

// now use "list"
```

If you need something re-usable, you're going to have to get your hands dirty building (and probably parsing) expression-trees (`System.Linq.Expression`). Not trivial.